# Segmentation fault: 11 in a program of multithread in C using pthread library

Tags: c, pthreads

I need to make a program using the pthread C library to work with threads. The text of the task says: There is a corridor that has a single lane for two directions and there are two types of employees who will cross the corridor to reach the opposite side of it. There are type 1 employees who go from left to right and type 2 employees who go from right to left. In this corridor there is an attendant who cleans this corridor when no one passes through it. When cleaning the corridor, the employees of both sides wait for it to end, otherwise, if the corridor is occupied, the employee says he cannot clean and go to sleep 2 seconds. 
When I compile this program the GCC compiler returns 5 Warning but no error. When I run the program, a Segmentation fault immediately appears: 11.

This is the program code updated:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include <unistd.h>


//global variables 
int c1,c2; //counters for imp1, imp2
pthread_mutex_t m1, m2;
sem_t corridor; 
double clean = 0.5;

//implementation thread attendant
void* attendant(void* arg){
    sleep(1); //rest 1 seconds
    if (c1==0 && c2==0){
        sem_wait(&corridor);
        printf("I'm starting to clean up\n");
        sleep(clean);
        printf ("I finished cleaning\n");
        sem_post(&corridor);
        }else{
           printf ("I can't clean, the corridor is busy\n");
        }
    return NULL;
}


//thread employee type 1
void* emp1(void *arg){
    printf("I'm the number %d of em1\n", c1);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m1); //beginning critical section
    c1++;                    //it increases to signal the presence of a thread of the same type that wants to enter the corridor
    if (c1 == 1){            //the thread is the only one in the corridor. Can pass
        printf ("I am the first of my group emp1\n");
        sem_wait(&corridor);  //takes possession of the corridor
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m1); //allows other threads of the same type to pass in the corridor since it was the first in his group. End of critical section

    // invents "passage" function

    pthread_mutex_lock(&m1);  //beginning of the critical section. Once crossed the corridor, the variable c1 is modified. A mutex is used to avoid inconsistency
    c1--;
    if(c1 == 0){
        printf ("I am the last of my group emp1\n");
        sem_post(&corridor);
    } //if c1 == 0, it is the last thread imp1 and releases the corridor
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m1); //end critical section
    return NULL;
}


//thread employee type 2 
void* emp2(void *arg){
    printf("I'm the number %d of emp2\n", c2);
    pthread_mutex_lock(&m2); //beginning critical section
    c2++;                    //it increases to signal the presence of a thread of the same type that wants to enter the corridor
    if (c2 == 1){            // the thread is the only one in the corridor. Can pass
        printf ("I am the first of my group emp2\n");
        sem_wait(&corridor);  //takes possession of the corridor
    }
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m2); //allows other threads of the same type to pass in the corridor since it was the first in his group. End of critical sectionritica

    // invents "passage" function

    pthread_mutex_lock(&m2);  //beginning of the critical section. Once crossed the corridor, the variable c1 is modified. A mutex is used to avoid inconsistency
    c2--;
    if(c2 == 0){
        printf ("I am the last of my group emp2\n");
        sem_post(&corridor);
    }//if c1 == 0, it is the last thread imp1 and releases the corridor
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&m2); //end critical section
    return NULL;
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    //pthread_t emp1, emp2, attendant;
    pthread_t idt;
    int r; //var random to create thread emp1 or emp2
    int i; //index 

    //variable initialization
    c1 = c2 = 0;
    pthread_mutex_init(&m1, NULL); 
    pthread_mutex_init(&m2, NULL);
    sem_init(&corridor,0,1); 

    pthread_create(&idt,NULL,attendant,NULL); 
    while(i<40){
        sleep(1);
        r = rand()%2;
        if(r==0){
            printf("Employee creation 1\n");
            pthread_create(&idt,NULL,emp1,NULL);
        }else{
            printf("Employee creation 2\n");
            pthread_create(&idt,NULL,emp2,NULL);
        }
        i++;
    pthread_join(idt, NULL);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please fix the warnings, then see if that cures the problem. Warnings should be treated as errors.

Comment: Debugging 101: As a beginner never ignore the warnings. You're missing `unistd.h` for sleep. Within main you do not need to make emp1,emp2, attendent of type pthread_t. Lastly within `pthread_create` pass the callback as reference `&`. There could still be more issues but there are just the ones I can eyeball.

Comment: Do not manually mark answers [SOLVED] in the question title.  It is already clearly indicated that the question has an accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pthread_t emp1, emp2, attendant;` shadows the functions with the same names, so `pthread_create(&idt,NULL,attendant,NULL);` passes the uninitialized value of the variable `attendant` to `pthread_create` as function pointer instead of the function `void* attendant(void* arg)`.

Remove the variables, you are not using them at all.

Also you forgot to `#include <unistd.h>`.

This will make your program compile: https://ideone.com/3CIb4J

Also your `main` function does not wait for the threads to finish, you should use `pthread_join` to wait for the threads.